# Error message when copying files over to Mac Server

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, finder, osx-server

I keep receiving the following error message when copying files, from my iMac and my Macbook, over to my Mac Mini Server.

> The Finder can’t complete the operation because some data in
>   “filename.pdf” can’t be read or written. (Error code -36)

But regardless of the error message, single files will still copy over. Multiple files however, will copy the first file, then kick the error message and stop.

Really a pain when I have a folder with 100's of images and I have to copy each image over individually!

However, when I copy files from a PC Desktop or Laptop to the Mac Server, no error message occurs.

I've been dealing with this issue for months and have not found a solution. I get the same message no matter what type of file it is.....PDF, JPG, DOC, Ai, etc.

Can anybody help??

Comment: Do you get the error when copying files via the Terminal?

Comment: I have never tried copying via Terminal. I was hoping for a more user-friendly approach

Comment: I can appreciate you wanting an easier approach however preforming the same tasks you did in Finder in Terminal is being done for diagnostic purposes, not intended to be a replacement!

Answer (score 1):

use `dot_clean`, the directory which is being copied and throwing the Error `Code 36`, the basics look like this:

Launch the Terminal (found in `/Applications/Utilities/` or with Spotlight)
At the command prompt, type:

```
dot_clean /Path/To/Directory/With/Problem/
```

When dot_clean is finished, attempt the file copy again and it should succeed with no error code
For example, if copying **~/Documents/FileBackups/** is the problematic directory, use:

```
dot_clean ~/Documents/FileBackups/
```

For more info see http://osxdaily.com/2015/02/21/fix-error-code-36-finder-mac-os-x/

Comment: We try to avoid one line answers. What does this do? How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

The Finder can be a problem when you drag huge file & folder structures in the IU.

Try using the `cp` command in Terminal if you're moving many hundreds of files, as it bypasses all the overhead the Finder imposes when manually dragging:

`cp [source_file] [target_destination]`

`cp -R ~/Desktop/BigFolderOfFiles /Volumes/<server>/<directory>`

From `man cp`:

> -R    If source_file designates a directory, cp copies the directory
>   and the entire subtree connected
>              at that point.  If the source_file ends in a /, the contents of the directory are copied rather
>              than the directory itself.

In Terminal, it is quite easy to do this without a lot of typing. You can drag folder icons into the terminal window and have the paths auto-expand, (and it escapes any spaces for you, too.)

You simply type:

`cp -R` [space] drag source folder **on the Mac** into Terminal window [space] drag target folder **on the server** into Terminal window, check to make sure it looks OK, then hit return. You can use the `-v` option to have Terminal list every file transferred.

Its worth a look at `man cp` to see the various options.  **Experiment first** to make sure you understand the concepts!

Comment: Thanks for the info! I was hoping for a more user-friendly route. I have minimal work in Terminal, but will give this a shot. You mentioned copying hundreds of files might be an issue, but even when I have a folder with 2 files in, it only ever copies the first, then kicks the error message.